# Firebase rules to allow users to access only a specific document (without any Authentication)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm building a web app using **firestore**, I want a user to create a firestore document and share the document id as a link to someone (`example.com/id?1z32AWS5Wqt5DBlHnCm0`) so that the person with the link can also view and update that firestore document.

Note that there is **no Authentication involved**, anyone can create a document and send the link to someone. If needed I can also use the anonymous signin (`signInAnonymously()`) option.

Now I need to write **database rules** to:

1. Prevent users from searching the whole collection to find all the other documents in the collection, i.e. using `.get()` method to create a `querysnapshot` and then looping through it to find all the docs.
2. Allow users to view and update only the collection that they have the collection id for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 is possible by allowing only `get` access but not `list`.  `read` is both `get` and `list`, so you will have to be clear that only the `get` method is allowed.  [Read about granular permissions in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations).

2 is not really possible.  Just knowing the name of a collection is enough for anyone to try to access it.  You can't "password protect" a collection securely.  You have to come up with some constraints about the user, using Firebase Authentication, in order to control access.